# How to change input name and db name?

Tags: forms, validation, codeigniter, input

I build a registration form with CodeIgniter. I have a question.

As an example, one of the field from my form

```
<input type="text" name="username">
```

But in database, I will use another name instead of username such as user. How do I do it?

So, on the form it will be username, but in the database its name will be user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will clear the whole flow (**comments** may help to understand better)

**View:**

```
<form action="/user/register" method="post">
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <input name="pass" type="password" />
  <input name="age" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
        {
            // if validation success
            if($validation)
            {
                /*
                Mapping form fields with DB fields
                Assuming below as fields in DB
                user, password, age
                */
                $data['user'] = $this->input->post('username');
                $data['password'] = $this->input->post('pass');
                $data['age'] = $this->input->post('age');

                // Add user
                $this->user_mode->add_user($data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);
    }

    public function add_user($data)
    {
         $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
}
```

To understand please read the **[Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)** section of CI User manual.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I am newbie in CodeIgniter. This example really helpful. The answers is actually using array. Thanks again.

Comment: I have did it now, If I got what you mean "Please mark the answer" :)